# Bind appsettings.json array section to generic class with generic list property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have to read some values from appsettings.json using `IOptionsSnapshot` and return them through the API endpoint

```
"adConfig": [
{
  "id": 3,
  "adDef": [
    {
      "type": "number",
      "key": "somekey",
      "displayName": "Rules",
      "values": [
        0,
        1
      ],
      "regex": null
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "key": "anotherkey",
      "displayName": "Some state",
      "values": [
        "some string value",
        "another string value"
      ],
      "regex": null
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": 1
....
}
]
```

For this porpose I created 2 classes to use to bind the settings.

```
public class AdDataModel<T>
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string key{ get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public List<T> Values { get; set; }
    public string regex { get; set; }

}

public class AdConfigurationModel
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public List<AdDataModel<dynamic>> AdDefinition { get; set; }
}
```

In the Startup.cs I use this code to bind the settings to the classes:

```
services.Configure<List<AdConfigurationModel>>(Configuration.GetSection("adConfig"));
```

So far so good. I inject this into the Controller class but the problem is that `AdDataModel.Values` are aways of type `object<string>` ( which is not the case for the first element of `adDef:Values` subsection). Is there any way to achive Values to be from type `int` or `string` based on the values in appsettings.json?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using dynamic why don't you just use strongly typed model?

Comment: Have you tried using public List<AdDataModel<int>> AdDefinition { get; set; } ?

Comment: I will lose string values if I use int in the second subsection of adDef:values

Comment: The problem is that (for scalar types) `Configuration` only ever returns strings that are then converted to other types, but since your collection is `List<dynamic>` (which, type-wise, is equivalent to `List<object>`), it figures no further conversion is necessary, so you always get strings. There is no simple way around this if you don't want to re-do all the configuration plumbing. It is the client, and not the configuration itself, that determines the type of the values.